# Need help loop my try and catch statements in java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, try-catch

I am calling this method and it works perfectly for the most part. Not sure if this is enough code for you guys to extrapolate from and figure out my problem, but I guess I will give it a shot..

When I enter an integer that is out of the bounds of the array or the file name does not exist, it throws the catch statement. I want it to then loop back to the question that the program is asking and not just continue to the rest of the program.. I keep getting an error when I throw the catch statement in the same while loop as the try statement. Thanks for the help, and I hope that was clear enough for you guys to understand.

```
public static String [][] placeCustomer(String [][] MovieSeats, int rows, int columns, String database)
{
    //Get user data and then write the name to the array space specified by the user..
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    try 
        {
            File readFile = new File(database);
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(readFile);

            while (reader.hasNextLine())
            {
                String user = reader.nextLine();
                System.out.println(user + " wants to sit in the theater. Where would you like to place him?");
                String lastUser = user;

                System.out.print("Row: ");
                int placeRow = input.nextInt();

                System.out.print("Column: ");
                int placeCol = input.nextInt();


                while (!MovieSeats[placeRow][placeCol].equals("Seat Empty |")) //If element in 2-D array reads empty, then tell user.
                {
                    System.out.println("Sorry that seat is already taken.. try a different location.."); //Give them another chance to change location
                    System.out.println("Please enter a new location for " + user);
                    System.out.print("Row: ");

                    placeRow = input.nextInt();

                    System.out.print("Column: ");
                    placeCol = input.nextInt();

                    if (MovieSeats[placeRow][placeCol].equals("Seat Empty |")) //If it is empty, allow user to fill the 2-D element..
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                }

                if (MovieSeats[placeRow][placeCol].equals("Seat Empty |"))
                {


                    while (MovieSeats[placeRow][placeCol].equals("Seat Empty |")) 
                    {
                        System.out.println("The customer " + user + " has been placed at row " + placeRow + " and the column " + placeCol + ".");
                        System.out.println();


                        MovieSeats[placeRow][placeCol] = user;

                        System.out.println("The current seating \n________________________");

                        viewFilledTheater(MovieSeats, rows, columns);

                        System.out.println();
                    }
                }

                else 
                {
                    System.out.println("Please enter a valid value for the program to understand where you would like to place the customer...");   
                }


            }
        }



            //If the file does not exist, then catch the exception, print this statement and exit the program..

            catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
            {
                System.out.println("The movie theater will remain empty because \nwe cannot find the customer list with the name you provided..");

            }

            catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
            {
                System.out.println("I am sorry, but the integer you entered is not within the proper bounds of the theater..");
            }







        return MovieSeats;
```

Answer (score 1):

while, I have a detailed look at your code, I think you can just make it more simple. You want  `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` to be catched and then terminal re-ask the client to input the placeRow, placeCol, so, you should put the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`  catch clause inside the while loop, while put the FileNotFoundException catch clause outside the while loop.

Below is a simple demo on how to put the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException try-catch clause to meet you need

```
while(true){
    System.out.println(user
    + " wants to sit in the theater. Where would you like to place him?");
    String lastUser = user;
    System.out.print("Row: ");
    int placeRow = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Column: ");
    int placeCol = input.nextInt();
    try{
        if(!MovieSeats[placeRow][placeCol].equals("Seat Empty |")){
            System.out.println("Sorry that seat is already taken.. try a different location..");
            System.out.println("Please enter a new location for "+ user);
            continue;
            }else{
            //set this seat occupied
            break;
        }

        }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        //e.printStackTrace();
        continue;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, first off, you throw Exceptions, which are caught by catch statements (that's why they call them catch statements).  Your problem is really just one of scoping.  Nest your try/catch inside the relevant loop.  Note that after an exception, the program resumes after the catch block(s).  If needed, you can have multiple nested try/catch statements.

Answer (score 0):

You should build a recursive method that does this:

step 1. check if the seats are available. If the seats are available, then place the user and display.

step 2. if the seats are not available, ask the user to see if the user likes to re-enter their choice. If YES, go to step 1. If NO, exit.

that way no matter how many times the user chooses the wrong values, he will always be given a choice to re-enter. Your program will never exit until the user chooses to.

I hope this gives you some idea. Good Luck.